# Design for m-to-n relation with unidirectional attribute(s)

Tags: database-design

Assume I have a Table `StackBox` that holds items as `Item`. I allow `StackBox` to have multiple `Item` and I allow `Item` to be in different `StackBox`. It is obviously an *m-to-n* relation. Solving this with an according *m-to-n mapping table* is easy.

But my problem here is the thing that I want to store the information **in which order** many `Item` are stored inside a `StackBox`. I could e.g. add a column to the *m-to-n mapping table*. Is this a valid solution even though I never want to ask "*At which places does `Item` occur*"? I am only interested in "*At which place inside `StackBox` is `Item` with id **x***"?

The other option would be to create two additional tables of course. One for the mappings from `StackBox` to `Item` that just contains two index tables and another one for the mappings from `Item` to `StackBox` that contains the two index columns plus e.g. an additional column *position*.

I hope my question is clear. Please let me know if I should clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could e.g. add a column to the m-to-n mapping table. Is this a valid solution?

Yes, this solution desrcibes best your scenario. A table with `(StackBox, Item, Position)` and a `unique` constraint on `(StackBox, Position)` (meaning only one item in each place/position) and probably another `unique` constraint on `(StackBox, Item)` (unless you can have an item twice or more in a stackbox).

The table would be like (I assume the other two tables have primary keys `StackBoxID` and `ItemID` and are `INT`, adjust accordingly to your design):

```
CREATE TABLE StackBoxItem
( StackBoxID INT NOT NULL, 
  ItemID INT NOT NULL, 
  Position INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (StackBoxID, Position),
  UNIQUE (StackBoxID, ItemID),
  FOREIGN KEY (StackBoxID) 
    REFERENCES StackBox (StackBoxID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ItemID) 
    REFERENCES Item (ItemID)
) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! But woudn't it be `PRIMARY KEY (StackBoxID, ItemID)` and `UNIQUE KEY (StackBoxID, Position)`? Where `StackBoxID` and `ItemID` are according foreign keys. That way I would have an *m-to-n* relation and would ensure unique appearance of `Item` in `StackBox` - which I too would like to ensure - didn't mention that in my question?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter which is the Primary Key and which is the Unique constraint.